# windows network discovery with batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, networking, discovery

I want to turn on network discovery on domain with a batch file, is that possible? I've seen so far how on local, but I can't fugure how to do on domain.

EDIT : I want to turn it "on" on a single computer/user, not on the server.

Comment: Do you mean turn it on for all clients in a Windows Domain?

Comment: do you already have a list of all machines in the domain?

Comment: I mean for a single machine. Turn on discovery on PC or user XXX on the domain

Comment: This seems like the sort of thing that would be better configured via GPO.  [Have you seen this?](http://jamessummerlin.com/2012/07/using-group-policy-to-enable-network-discovery-in-a-domain/)